# Creating Menu containing List of Layers that can be added to MXD using arcpy.mapping

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

Is it possible to create a list of layers (residing in something like a menu) that can be selected and added to an mxd using arcpy.mapping?

I've been using the bit of code below to add a single layer. The code is within a Scripting Tool and is added to a toolbar as a Geoprocessing Tool.

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping

#Data Location
parcels = r'P:\Mapping\Data\Land.gdb\Parcels\Parcels'

#Get the map document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

#Get the data frame
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]

#Create new layer
parcelLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(parcels)

#Add the layer to the map at the bottom of the TOD in data frame 0
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, parcelLayer, "TOP")

#Refresh things
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, df, parcelLayer
```

I want to avoid creating a script for each dataset that I want to add programatically to an mxd, but I also want to stay within Python/ArcPy as I have no business trying to do this within ArcObjects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this effort seems unnecessary. Consider instead [creating a Folder Connection](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000044p000000) to a shared folder containing your workgroup's most frequently used [layer files](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000013000000).

[image: Create Folder Connection]

It is then a simple matter of expanding the folder connection and dragging and dropping the desired layer(s) into your map document.

The one caveat to this is that I would recommend **not** using drive letters if you have mapped network shares to drive letters, as these may not exist or be the same for everyone (unless you are quite diligent in setting them up and do not have conflicting drive letters). Instead use the fully-qualified [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path (e.g. `\\server\folder\subfolder` instead of `X:\subfolder` where `X:` is mapped to `\\server\folder`) in both the layer file itself and the folder connection.

Comment: While I totally agree with @blah238's suggestion, if you do decide to go through with building a custom data loading utility, I encourage you to check out my answer to [Symbolizing Layers in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31653/symbolizing-layers-in-postgis), where I detail some concepts that I implemented in an ArcView 3.x custom data loader.

Answer (score 1):

I know what you are getting at, I've been intending to build the same thing.  My plan is to use an Addon to make a toolbar with a combo-box dropdown that has all the layers I use frequently.

Then you can load up the addon and just click which layers you want to add for each map without having to navigate through the mess of network drives, geodatabases, etc,etc.

I don't know how to do it yet but I found this helpful:

http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseID=1965

Answer (score -1):

At the moment this is only possible with the Java or the. NET SDK. The Code for listing layers and adding them to the mxd is nearly the same on all these customizing platforms. The point is, that arcpy does not support any UI Controls. With 10.1 ESRI introduced at least Python based Addins, but its still not possible to use rudimentary UI Controls such as Dropdown Lists or Comboboxes. For UI Customizing you have to take the way over ArcObjects and the SDKs.

We combined an enterp ise search index based on solr (  single search textbox) where you can search our metadata repository and add layers which are found. You can achieve a pretty similar thing by setting up an ArcGIS server search service and use the arcgis onboardenterprise search feature. I think that would helpmost of your users.